# Creating a named pipe in Java with exec calls

Tags: java, exec, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a named pipe in Java with exec calls. I have this line of code

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c \"mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s\"");
```

But when I look for `~/myFifo` after the call, it is not there. Is there any reason this would not work?

I also tried without the `/bin/sh -c` bit, but it didn't work either.

**EDIT**

```
final String [] cmds = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "\"mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s\""};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Comment: Never, ever use `Runtime.exec(String)`. Use `Runtime.exec(String[])`

Comment: Try running /bin/sh -c alone, and then writing in the rest to Process.getOutputStream();

Comment: @thatotherguy I broke the commands up into `String []`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: How do you run the code? Under which user?

Comment: @erip Please update your question with the code you used with `Runtime.exec(String[])`

Comment: @DmitriiSemenov I own the project.

Comment: You use the ~ in your path. Are you sure it is the same when you run the code and when you check the file afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write out the third argument, you'll get this:

```
"mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s"
```

And if you try to run that in a shell, you'll see that it doesn't work:

```
$ "mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s"
bash: mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s: No such file or directory
```

Just remove the literal quotes you added:

```
final String [] cmds = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s"};
```

and remember to read from the `Process.getInputStream()`.